# Google Cloud Endpoints generated iOS Client not working

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a python webservice running locally using GAE Python SDK 1.8.3. After annotating the API and generating iOS client classes using Google Cloud Endpoints Service Generator I'm trying to call a remote procedure using it.

If I test my api using API Explorer, everything works just fine.

When I call using the iOS client, the call is received by the webservice, however the request cannot be decoded correctly. This is my first time using the Endpoints API so I don't know what is wrong.

What seems to be happening is that my request object is being wrapped in a "resource" key in the query JSON. Now, when my webservice tries to decode it, it yields a warning saying "No variant found for unrecognized field: resource". And, as my object is wrapped inside this key, it is skipped and never decoded to a message.

When the call is made using the API Explorer the object is not wrapped, so everything works.

This is what I'm doing in my webservice:

```
@endpoints.method(SearchRequest, 
                  ContactListResponse,
                  path='search', http_method='post',
                  name='api.search')
def search(self, request):
    user = request.user
    number = request.number
```

This is how I call it from iOS:

```
GTLMyAPIMessagesSearchRequest * request = [[GTLMyAPIMessagesSearchRequest alloc] init];
request.user = @"+552199881234";
request.number = @"+5521717171";


GTLQueryMyAPI *query = [GTLQueryMyAPI queryForApiSearchWithObject:request];
[service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                GTLMyAPIMessagesContactListResponse* object,
                                                NSError *error)
{
    NSArray* contacts = object.contacts;
}
```

Am I doing anything incredibly wrong here?

Comment: This is under review : https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9821

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a great solution but a patch for now.  I have the same problem when doing iOS endpoints localhost testing. However when I use the deployed backend I remove this line and everything is fine.

```
    auth.shouldAuthorizeAllRequests = YES;
```

The "resource" key wrapping issue only happens when I add the line above to use localhost.  So this morning I'm not using localhost, just the deployed version.  Let me know if you fix the issue. :)  Obviously pointing to the deployed version is not preferred for testing.

Comment: user2697002, I still haven't tried the deployed version. Maybe this should fix the issue, as soon as I can I will try your solution and if it works I'll mark it as an accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: YES! It did work on deployment! I'm marking this as accepted as it led me to know that this works on appspot.
I'm posting the workaround for this to work on development as another answer as it might help others.

Answer (score 4):

This is an annoying bug from iOS to Endpoints for local testing.  I hope they fix it soon. :)

BTW instead of modifying QGTQueryMyAPI.m (which is a generated file). I do Theo's fix just after I create the query instead.  So all of my queries that send data look like this (and I set that one flag to switch from localhost to deployed in other places too).

```
GTLQueryMyApi *query = [GTLQueryMyApi queryForSearchWithObject:someGtlObject];

if (LOCAL_HOST_TESTING) {
    [query setJSON:someGtlObject.JSON];        
}
```

Comment: Nice touch, Dave. This is really easier to implement so you don't have to change the generated code all the time. Never thought of that!!! =)

Comment: This is still an issue as of Oct 2014, and this fix still works!

Answer (score 0):

Alright! user2697002's answer showed me that this works when the webservice is deployed.

For development to work correctly this is the workaround I did.

The generated API uses a template like this for all queries in GTLQueryMyAPI.m

```
+ (id)queryForSearchWithObject:(GTLMyAPIMessagesSearchRequest *)object {
  if (object == nil) {
    GTL_DEBUG_ASSERT(object != nil, @"%@ got a nil object", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    return nil;
  }
  NSString *methodName = @"myapi.search";
  GTLQueryMyAPI *query = [self queryWithMethodName:methodName];
  query.bodyObject = object;
  query.expectedObjectClass = [GTLMyAPIMessagesContactListResponse class];
  return query;
}
```

For this to work on development server one could substitute all these lines

```
query.bodyObject = object;
```

With

```
query.JSON = object.JSON;
```

This stops from wrapping the JSON in a "resource" field. Somehow I believe this shouldn't be done on deployment release version.

Comment: Theo, can you post how do you configure the iOS client api to connect to the local server instead of the online server?

Comment: @Teg, Sorry that I didn't see your comment before. Do you still need this or have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still experimenting but believe this is the proper way (swift) to set up for testing on localhost....

```
let _service = GTLServiceBackendAPI();
_service.allowInsecureQueries = true;
_service.isRESTDataWrapperRequired = false;
_service.retryEnabled = true;
_service.fetcherService.allowLocalhostRequest = true;
_service.rpcURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/rpc?prettyPrint=true")
```